# Checking file names in a directory with entries in an excel spreadsheet; What am I doing wrong?

Tags: excel, powershell, scripting, directory

I'm attempting to write a PowerShell script (my first ever, so be gentle) to go through all the file names in a directory and check if they exist in an excel spreadsheet that I have. If a file name does exist in both, I want to move/copy that file to a new directory.

Right now it runs with no errors, but nothing actually happens.

So far I have:

```
#open excel sheet
$objexcel=new-object -com excel.application
$workbook=$objexcel.workbooks.open("<spreadsheet location>")
#use Sheet2
$worksheet = $workbook.sheets.Item(2)

#outer loop: loop through each file in directory
foreach ($_file in (get-childitem -path "<directory to search>"))
{
    $filename = [system.IO.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_)

    #inner loop: check with every entry in excel sheet (if is equal)
    $intRowCount = ($worksheet.UsedRange.Rows).count
    for ($intRow = 2 ; $intRow -le $intRowCount ; $intRow++)
    {
        $excelname = $worksheet.cells.item($intRow,1).value2
        if ($excelname -eq $filename)
        { #move to separate folder
            Copy-Item -path $_file -Destination "<directory for files to be copied to>"
        }
        #else do nothing
    }
}
#close excel sheet
$workbook.close()
$objexcel.quit()
```

Comment: Have you opened it in ISE, set a breakpoint, and stepped through the code to see where you're running into a problem? Some value somewhere is not what you are expecting.

Comment: Commenting to mention the use of `foreach` in Powershell.  As an example, `foreach` statements usually follow `Foreach ($server in $servers){Test-Connection -count 1 $server}` format.  Where `$servers=Get-Content c:\scripts\servers.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to define `$filename` based on the current object (`$_`), but that variable isn't populated in a `foreach` loop:

```
$filename = [system.IO.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_)
```

Because of that `$filename` is always `$null` and therefore never equal to `$excelname`.

Replace the `foreach` loop with a `ForEach-Object` loop if you want to use `$_`. I'd also recommend to read the Excel cell values into an array outside that loop. That improves performance and allows you to use the array it in a `-contains` filter, which would remove the need for having a loop in the first place.

```
$intRowCount = ($worksheet.UsedRange.Rows).count
$excelnames = for ($intRow = 2; $intRow -le $intRowCount; $intRow++) {
  $worksheet.cells.item($intRow,1).value2
}

Get-ChildItem -Path "<directory to search>" |
  Where-Object { $excelnames -contains $_.BaseName } |
  Copy-Item -Destination "<directory for files to be copied to>"
```

On a more general note: you shouldn't use variable names starting with an underscore. They're too easily confused with properties of the current object variable (`$_name` vs. `$_.name`).

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much. I really had no idea what I was doing - I've got a lot to learn! I'm still having a hard time understanding the pipeline concept though...