# Powershell lookup values using excel, change name folders and move them; no matches

Tags: excel, powershell

Linked with [Checking file names in a directory with entries in an excel spreadsheet; What am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975583/checking-file-names-in-a-directory-with-entries-in-an-excel-spreadsheet-what-am)

Powershool noob.
I have a large list of folders (eg 2018_5486975_rest, 2017_6485272_rest, ...). I'm trying to auto rename and move some to another location using an Excel file. The Excel file has, among others, the columns 'ID' and 'Date'. Eg '5486975' and corresponding'11/09/2018' (dd/mm/yyyy). If there's a match in ID, I'd like to replace the year in the folder name (first 4 digits) with the date in the Excel file (in yyyy-mm-dd) and move the folder to another location. So far I've managed to extract the columns in two variables, and list the folder names. The code I'm using doesn't return any matches though (even though I know there are matches).

- Why don't I get any matches?
- Do I have to use Substring, how do I do this?
- If there is a match, how do I replace the date part of the folder name with the corresponding date and move it?

```
    #Initiate Forms, enter path Excel file, save path in variable 
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{
    Filter = '(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx'} #enter desired file type

[void]$FileBrowser.ShowDialog()
$PadExcel = $FileBrowser.FileNames; #Save file path in variable

#Initiate Excel
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application #Application layer
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($PadExcel) #Workbook layer
$WorkSheet = $Workbook.Sheets.Item(1) #worksheet layer

#Select ID's in Excel
$startRowID = 2
$IDExcel = @()
$count = $Worksheet.Cells.Item(65536,2).End(-4162)
for($startRowID=2; $startRowID -le $count.row; $startRowID++)
{
 $IDExcel += $Worksheet.Cells.Item($startRowID, 2).Value()
}

#Select Dates in Excel
$startRowDate = 2
$DateExcel = @()
$count2 = $Worksheet.Cells.Item(65536,25).End(-4162)
for($startRowDate=2; $startRowDate -le $count2.row; $startRowDate++)
{
 $DateExcel += $Worksheet.Cells.Item($startRowDate, 25).Value()
}
$DateExcel=$DateExcel | Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"

Get-ChildItem -path "C:\Users\User\Documents\Testfolders" |
Where-Object {$IDExcel -contains $_.Name} > "C:\Users\User\Documents\Testfolders\test.txt"


## Close Excel
$objExcel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objExcel)
Stop-Process -Name "Excel"
```

Comment: Try running each line in the console and then check if the variable contains the value you would expect. For instance, does $Worksheet.Cells.Item(2, 2).Value() come back with the right value?

Comment: @StephenBurrows, the Excel variables relay the right values, eg an array of ID's 5874648, 8754625, ... and dates eg 2019-01-23, 2018-05-26. So I can assume that is working right at least.